# How to bring trailing minus to leading minus in tr command

Tags: excel, shell, csv, unix, translate

I am having a issue with tr command to translate the file from .csv to normal excel.

My input file is .csv file delimited with |.

I have used the below command.

```
tr '|' ',' < TEST.csv > OUTPUT.csv
```

After execution of tr command.

```
Input:
A|101
2|202-

Output: 
A 101
2 202-

Expected output:
A 101
B -202
```

Can anyone help me to translate a .csv file to normal excel with minus sign in front of the field using tr command.

or after tr execution is there any way to bring the trailing minus to leading minus.

or any other possible script to bring the trailing minus to leading minus.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you think that `tr` will change the positions of anything? `tr` operates on a char-by-char basis. It can do only 1 thing, and that, (in very high-baroque english) is `**tr**ansliterate`. ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this;

```
tr '|' ' ' <  TEST.csv  | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  if ($i ~ /-$/) $i = "-"substr($i,1,length($i)-1); print }' > OUTPUT.csv
```

Example;

```
user@host:/tmp$ cat TEST.csv 
A|101
2|202-

user@host:/tmp$ tr '|' ' ' <  TEST.csv  | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  if ($i ~ /-$/) $i = "-"substr($i,1,length($i)-1); print }' 
A 101
2 -202
```

Comment: I have executed the above script but still i can find the minus in trailing end. My customer requirement is to get the minus sign at leading end. kindly provide some UNIX script to translate a .csv file with minus at leading end